# Export specific agent trajectory in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm new to AnyLogic. I'm trying to export the pedestrian trajectory from my model. I used an event updated every simulation time unit with code: traceln("When time is "+ (int) time()+ " ," + getId()+"is at ("+getX()+","+getY()+")"), and get several agents' id and location information with specific time.
[Anylogic console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Hs2.png)
But when I use textFile.println() with same command to export them, the information I get in outside text file is only one agent.
[text file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAcu0.png)
Is there anyway I can export all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the code from within the pedestrian agent (if you defined a custom agent) or use the `ped` keyword within pedestrian-library blocks code sections (`ped.getX()/Y`).

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I used traceToDB() to load information in console to database and exported it.